# Why doesn't Java seem to respect my classpath?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the [jt400.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/) in my directory:

```
/path
    /jt400.jar
    /Test.java
```

The contents of Test.java:

```
import java.sql.*;

//import com.ibm.as400.*;  // To be uncommented later
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "jdbc:as400//myserver.domain.com;DSN=DB2;Uid=name;Pwd=password;";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    }
}
```

I compile this:

```
 $ javac -cp jt400.jar Test.java
```

And try to run:

```
 $ java -cp jt400.jar Test.java
```

Which produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:as400://myserver.domain.com;DSN=DB2;Uid=name;Pwd=password;
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:635)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
        at Killer.main(Test.java:8)
```

Now, inside jt400.jar I have verified:

```
$ jar -tf jt400.jar | grep class | grep AS400 | grep Driv
com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.class
```

Yet, when I uncomment the import line, I get

```
Test.java:3: package com.ibm.as400 does not exist
import com.ibm.as400.*;
```

So either I completely misunderstand Java's classpath and import mechanism, or it sure seems like it's not respecting the classpath that I provide.

How can I solve this problem? I haven't been able to find anything useful on Google or Stackoverflow, but I don't spend much time in Java so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Or, third possibility: the JDBC connection URL is wrong.

Comment: There is `:` missing. Try `jdbc:as400://myserver.domain.com;DSN=DB2;Uid=name;Pwd=password;`

Comment: Isn't the jar automatically included by default since it's in the same directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String url = "jdbc:as400//myserver.domain.com;DSN=DB2;Uid=name;Pwd=password;";
```

You're missing a colon, it should be:

```
String url = "jdbc:as400://myserver.domain.com;DSN=DB2;Uid=name;Pwd=password;";
//                      /\
```

Comment: +1 nice spot. Sometimes typo answers are very helpful.

Comment: Additionally I also had to do `DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver());` before doing `getConnection`. Also had to put the username/password in there.

Comment: Yep - the missing `:` and the `registerDriver` is what I needed